# How to change logo size of mobile version. Logo scales down to tiny image

Tags: magento2.4.6, mobile, logo

I've been trawling to interwebs and cant seem to find anything that points to the answer for this issue.

I'm working on a magento 2.4.6 site. The logo is tiny on the mobile version. The sites at [www.psychedelicpsychotherapy.io/](https://www.psychedelicpsychotherapy.io/)

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? The logo is being scaled down to 80x22. I want it to take up whatever space is available on the mobile version depending on the resolution.

Thanks in Advance

[image: Logo Issue mobile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you please replace your .logo CSS from custom.css line no. 240 to as below

```
.logo {
    max-width: max-content;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

see the attached image which I have done on my side Is this solution okay for you?

[image]

If my solution is right so accept the solution and give an upvote!
Thanks.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot! That works when I add it into custom.css in the debugger but when I edit the actual file it doesn't over ride the previous css rules. Is the custom.css file in /public_html/pub/media/porto/web/css/custom.css a cached file that gets generated from another file?

Comment: Yes, your file path is wrong, your actual file path is app/design/vendor_name/theme_name/web/css/custom.css this is my assumed file path hope this is the right please find your custom.css file this

Comment: Thanks, but when I do the command "find . -name custom.css" in an ssh terminal the only result I get is /pub/media/porto/web/css/custom.css  Can I hire your to give me some help one on one? I need a little tutoring :-)